# Why I couldn't able to add mod_proxy.c in Apache?

Tags: apache, tomcat

In my `httpd.conf` file I have these lines:

```
LoadModule proxy_module  /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
AddModule  mod_proxy.c



ProxyPass         /myapp  http://ec2-54-242-101-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse  /myapp  http://ec2-54-242-101-196.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/
```

When I restart the apache I get the error like this :

```
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'AddModule', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

I followed the tutorial form [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/proxy-howto.html).

Where I'm making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddModule` directive is not present in httpd 2.0 and later. Remove it.

Are you really using Apache httpd 1.3? Read the last line on that whole page you referenced. Also, are you really using Tomcat 4.1? Try using the documentation for the version you are actually using. In fact, forget the Tomcat documentation. Go for the [httpd documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).